# How to display the image file size taken from Flutter image_picker plugin?

Tags: image, flutter, dart, plugins, filesize

I am creating a Flutter app and I want to show the image file size (in kb/mb) when the user gets an image from either the gallery or camera.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5zbA.png)

Right now, when the user gets an image, it displays a thumbnail and text "Image Selected" on the screen, as shown in the picture. I want it to also display the image file size under "Image Selected".

```
File _image;
final picker = ImagePicker();

Future getImageFromCamera() async {
  final pickedImage = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

  setState(() {
    if (pickedImage != null) {
      _image = File(pickedImage.path);
    } else {
      print('No image selected.');
    }
  });
}

Future getImageFromGallery() async {
  final pickedImage = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

  setState(() {
    if (pickedImage != null) {
      _image = File(pickedImage.path);
    } else {
      print('No image selected.');
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using a function that will provide you with the file size as a neat formatted string.

Imports:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:math';
```

Output:

```
//if(await _image.exists())
print(getFilesizeString(bytes: _image.lengthSync()));
// Output Example: 17 Bytes, 30MB, 7GB
```

Function:

```
// Format File Size
static String getFileSizeString({@required int bytes, int decimals = 0}) {
  if (bytes <= 0) return "0 Bytes";
  const suffixes = [" Bytes", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB"];
  var i = (log(bytes) / log(1024)).floor();
  return ((bytes / pow(1024, i)).toStringAsFixed(decimals)) + suffixes[i];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Check the file length using readasbytes;

```
//final bytes = (await image.readAsBytes()).lengthInBytes;
final bytes = image.readAsBytesSync().lengthInBytes;
final kb = bytes / 1024;
final mb = kb / 1024;
```

Comment: When I try this, it gives me the error, "The method 'readAsBytesSync' isn't defined for the type 'PickedFile'."                                                            

`Future getImageSize() async {
   final pickedImage = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
   final bytes = pickedImage.readAsBytesSync().lengthInBytes;
   final kb = bytes / 1024;
   final mb = kb / 1024;

   setState(() {    
     if (pickedImage != null) {
       _image = File(pickedImage.path);
     } else {
       print('No image selected.');
     }
   });
}`

Comment: storedImage = File(pickedImage.path); // you should make the operation on File type not PickedFile

Answer (score 1):

Use [`length`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-io/File/length.html) or [`lengthSync`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-io/File/lengthSync.html) to get the size of the file. length or lengthSync would return the size in bytes, you need to convert it to kilo-bytes or mega-bytes.

Answer (score 0):

For Image picker

```
Future getImageSize() async {
 final pickedImage = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
 final bytes = pickedImage.readAsBytesSync().lengthInBytes;
 final kb = bytes / 1024;
  final mb = kb / 1024;
 setState(() {
  if (pickedImage != null) {
   var _image = File(pickedImage.path);
   } else {
   print('No image selected.');
   }
   });}
```